# Make a proper data frame from a pandas crosstab output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a multi-indexed output after pandas crosstab function which is shown below

```
sports        cricket      football      tennis
nationality   
IND           180          18            1     
UK            10           30            10
US            5            30            65
```

From the above, I would like to prepare below df.

Expected output:

```
nationality   cricket      football      tennis
IND           180          18            1     
UK            10           30            10
US            5            30            65
```

I tried the below code which is giving the wrong data frame.

```
df_tab.reset_index().iloc[:, 1:]


sports   cricket      football      tennis
IND      180          18            1     
UK       10           30            10
US       5            30            65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need also index and columns names together, first column is `index`, all another are columns (but looks same):

```
df = df_tab.rename_axis(index = None, columns= df_tab.index.name)
print (df)
nationality  cricket  football  tennis
IND              180        18       1
UK                10        30      10
US                 5        30      65

print (df.index)
Index(['IND', 'UK', 'US'], dtype='object')
```

If need print DataFrame without index:

```
print (df_tab.reset_index().to_string(index=False))
nationality  cricket  football  tennis
        IND      180        18       1
         UK       10        30      10
         US        5        30      65
```

EDIT: In DataFrame is always necessary index, so if need column from `nationality` use:

```
df = df_tab.reset_index().rename_axis(columns = None)
```

Comment: can you please share your output? I am getting different output

Comment: How can I make nationality as a first column, not an index

Comment: @Danish - Do you need in file, if use `df.to_csv()` ?

Comment: @Danish - because if need standard way for print always is necessary `index`

Comment: No, as a data frame with a first column as nationality.

Comment: Tried df_tab.rename_axis(index = None, columns= df_tab.index.name).reset_index() does not work.

Comment: @Danish - Can you check edit?